# How do I show all objects from my array and not just the 1 and also how do I do it in order?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How do I show all objects from my array and not just the 1 and also how do I do it in order? It's only showing 1 item and only the last item. So I have all of the objects listed but it is only giving me the same item and its also starting from the bottom.

```
let stoves = [
    {
        id: 1,
        brand: "Frigidaire",
        modelNumber: "FCRC3012AW",
        description: "30\" Electric Coil Top Range ",
        color: "White",
        price: "$450.00",
        qty: "",
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        brand: "Frigidaire",
        modelNumber: "FFEF3016VB",
        description: "30\" Electric Coil Top Range  - Self Clean",
        color: "Black",
        price: "$465.00",
        qty: "",
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        brand: "Frigidaire",
        modelNumber: "FFEF3016VW",
        description: "30\" Electric Coil Top Range  - Self Clean",
        color: "White",
        price: "$465.00",
        qty: "",
    },
```

```
stoves.forEach((item) => {
   
   brandLogo.src = 'imgs/brand-logos/frig.png';
   productDesc.innerHTML = `${item.description} `;
   modelNum.innerHTML = `<h5>Model Number:</h5>${item.modelNumber}`;
   price.innerHTML = `${item.price}`;
   
   });
}

applSection();

let appliances = stoves;

function init() {
   appliances.forEach(applSection);
}

init();
```

Comment: You should format that code so it doesn't contain any typos or syntax errors. You should also add in the relevant HTML for `brandLogo` etc as a [mcve] using the snippet function `[<>]` in the edit toolbar.

Comment: Right now you are updating the innerHTML for each iteration. You should either make use of something like appendChild https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild and adding a new item per iteration or store the full html inside a new variable to print it after your forEach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's only showing 1 item and only the last item. So I have all of the
> objects listed but it is only giving me the same item and its also
> starting from the bottom.

Your issue is that you loop over your array but you *assign* instead of accumelate  each time... so absolutely you'll get the last item.
So solution is to use a variable to accumelate your `objects` then finally assign it to `HTML`

```js
let stoves = [
    {
        id: 1,
        brand: "Frigidaire",
        modelNumber: "FCRC3012AW",
        description: "30\" Electric Coil Top Range ",
        color: "White",
        price: "$450.00",
        qty: "",
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        brand: "Frigidaire",
        modelNumber: "FFEF3016VB",
        description: "30\" Electric Coil Top Range  - Self Clean",
        color: "Black",
        price: "$465.00",
        qty: "",
    }]
let productsHTML = "";
stoves.forEach((item) => {
   const product = `<h5>Model Number: ${item.modelNumber}</h5>Description: ${item.description} <br/> Price: ${item.price} <hr/>`;
   productsHTML += product;
   });
productDesc.innerHTML = productsHTML;
```

```html
<div id="productDesc"/>
```

Comment: So your suggestion kinda works but I wasn't able to add everything here on stackover flow, is there so other platform I can show you on and possibly receive some additional help from you?

Answer (score 0):

**innerHTML =** will set innerHtml meaning that you will lose what you had before use **+=** instead it appends to existing

```
stoves.forEach((item) => {
   
   brandLogo.src = 'imgs/brand-logos/frig.png';
   productDesc.innerHTML += `${item.description} `;
   modelNum.innerHTML += `<h5>Model Number:</h5>${item.modelNumber}`;
   price.innerHTML += `${item.price}`;
   
   });
}
```